# How do I assign a query result (an email address) to a variable?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to assign a query result (an email address) to a variable.

I want that variable to be assigned to a button to open the current used mailing system and open a new mail with that email address.

```vb
Public valid_mail As Variant
    
Public Sub mail_list()
    valid_mail = "SELECT CustomerFACT.îééì FROM CustomerFACT WHERE (((CustomerFACT.[èìôåï ðééã]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ùí àéù ÷ùø]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ùí äì÷åç]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[îñôø òåñ÷]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*'));"
End Sub
    
Private Sub mail_70_Click()
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , valid_mail
End Sub
```

When I am not using the global variable valid_mail, but entering an email address in double quotes, it works.

Comment: You have substituted the query statement. You will have to assign the result of the query.

Comment: Didn't quite understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tested in my example. You need to substitute the results of the recordset.

```
Public valid_mail As Variant

Sub test()
    Dim DB As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set DB = CurrentDb
    
    strSQL = "select email from [table] "
    
    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    valid_mail = rs!email
    
    MsgBox valid_mail
End Sub
```

Substituting for yours would look like this:

```
Public valid_mail As Variant
Sub  mail_list()
    Dim DB As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set DB = CurrentDb
    
    strSQL = "SELECT CustomerFACT.ieei FROM CustomerFACT WHERE (((CustomerFACT.[eioai ðeea]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui aeu ÷uø]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui ai÷ac]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[inoø oan÷]) Like '*' & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & '*'));"
    
    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    valid_mail = rs!ieei
    
    ''MsgBox valid_mail
End Sub

Private Sub mail_70_Click()

call mail_list

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , valid_mail
End Sub
```

and Your sql statement is expressed incorrectly. It should be like below.

```
strSQL = "SELECT CustomerFACT.ieei FROM CustomerFACT WHERE (((CustomerFACT.[eioai ðeea]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui aeu ÷uø]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "'*)) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui ai÷ac]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[inoø oan÷]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*'));"
```

my anwer also mistyped.

```
Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "'*))
```

to

```
Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*'))
```

crrected sql is

```
strSQL = "SELECT CustomerFACT.ieei FROM CustomerFACT WHERE (((CustomerFACT.[eioai ðeea]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui aeu ÷uø]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[ui ai÷ac]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*')) Or (((CustomerFACT.[inoø oan÷]) Like '*" & Forms!CustomerLookUpFORM!searchbox & "*'));"
```

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot! seems to work, only that when I run it, it throwa an error "error 3061 too few parameters" and when I debug, the error occurs here - Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Comment: @EyalMarom, Your sql statement is expressed incorrectly. added at the end of the post.

Comment: It's exactly what I did. When debugging, the error leads to the OpenRecordset function, saying it needs more arguments (at least 1) and when I checked the syntax, the other possible arguments are optional. Can't figure it out.

Comment: @EyalMarom, My answer also had a typo.